# Why formatCurrency() in DT package gives error if the column name is not present?

Tags: r, shiny, dt

Imagine I'm using this code in a shiny application where columns are filtered using shiny input:

```
library(magrittr)
library(DT) # version 0.18

data_viz <- data.frame(Item = c("Milk", "Bread", "Flour"), Quantity = c(2,3,4), Price = c(4,5,6)) # Original data

data_table_viz <- data_viz[, c("Item", "Quantity")] # Filtering columns on the go using Shiny app input 

datatable(data = data_table_viz) %>% formatCurrency(c("Price")) # Throws error: You specified the columns: Price, but the column names of the data are  , Item, Quantity
```

It throws error:
Error in name2int(name, names, rownames) :
You specified the columns: Price, but the column names of the data are  , Item, Quantity

The error is understandable but I would like to avoid this error and instead ignore the column "Price" and render the remaining data. Below is a workaround:

```
datatable(data = data_table_viz) %>% formatCurrency(c("Price")[c("Price") %in% colnames(data_table_viz)])
```

It used to work until DT package version 0.13 but it stopped working afterwards.

It now throws error:
Error in mapply(FUN = f, ..., SIMPLIFY = FALSE) :
zero-length inputs cannot be mixed with those of non-zero length

Does anyone have other workarounds for this issue or should I keep using the older version of the package DT?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can add an `if` condition to check if the column is present.

```
library(magrittr)
library(DT)

dt <- datatable(data = data_table_viz) 
if('Price' %in% colnames(data_table_viz)) dt <- dt %>% formatCurrency("Price")
```

Comment: Thanks Ronak. It works. Although, if there were a lot of currency columns, you'll need to write if condition for each one of them separately. But at least the problem is solved for now. So I'm happy with it.